# Resolving host name

Tags: c, sockets

I can resolve hostname with

> getaddrinfo ()

And then to validate address. I can use

> connect(socket, sockaddr, len)

I'm not sure what connect does. Because if I try to modify hosts file e.g. modify ip-address for a host name. My connect() still works fine.

e.g.

> foo.bar 1.1.1.1 ---> foo.bar 2.2.2.2

Is there anyway to know oh, now no more 1.1.1.1 is valid, its 2.2.2.2

Comment: You can cache the result of the first lookup, and compare if subsequent lookups yield a different value from before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getaddrinfo()` translates `addrinfo` structs containing `sockaddr` structs that can in turn be used to `connect()` a socket, which only really cares about raw IPv4/IPv6/Unix Domain addresses. `connect()` needs raw addresses, but does not know or care at all where they came from (translated, hardcoded as 32 bit integers, etc.), and connecting to an address is not actually verification that a translated address was the "right" one, just that some server on the requested raw address was open on the requested port.

It also sounds like you want to cache translated addresses, which can often be beneficial, but you also seem to expect changed name mappings to be "pushed" to you. Linux systems generally do not cache address translations at the OS level unless you are running `nscd` (name service cache daemon), and even then there is no form of pushing updates to applications using DNS translation. You simply have to occasionally re-translate the names and see if the `sockaddr` has changed.

If you know that relevant name/address changes will be from frequent local `/etc/hosts` will modifications (a very unlikely scenario, in all likelihood!), you could consider using `inotify` to monitor that file for updates, flushing your local name cache when you see a change.

Comment: thanks. This helps. Yeah I cache transalated addresses and I don't want to do all time.  So if I understood correctly connect doesn't care about /etc/hosts .. so there isn't any API which cares? I see bind too. If they don't check against /etc/hosts/ then is there any way to try to verify this? (Of course you have suggested inotify, still wondering!)

Comment: @codemuncher There is no socket<->DNS API anywhere in Linux/POSIX. `getaddrinfo()` / `gethostbyname()` translate names to numeric addresses without caring if those addresses will be used. The system address translation service that `getaddrinfo()` calls queries `/etc/hosts` for overrides configured there before making external queries. Because `getaddrinfo()` is stateless and not a connection/event notification mechanism, there is no way for the system to signal changes, but you can watch the file to see if there could be a change to what you looked up earlier.

Comment: @codemuncher To clarify a bit further, all socket API calls including `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`, and `connect()` only care about numeric addresses for IPv4/v6. Host name translation is entirely separate from the sockets that might use the ultimately translated values. `inotify` is just an API to watch files and directories for changes, so it will only be able to tell you, e.g., that `/etc/hosts` was modified by somebody. This solution is pretty hackish, since it covers a pretty rare case and doesn't solve addresses being changed on DNS servers, which is much more common.